# Last character/words of strings are missing in expo built apk of a react-native app

Tags: android, react-native, expo, native-base

One of my screens in a react-native app has a simple UI of user-registration page. I have generated an android apk using the command `eas build -p android --profile preview`. The generated apk has no issues when running on emulator: Pixel 5 (this is the apk and not the app being run through Expo Go), but when I install it on a device - OnePlus 5t - it has a few strings incompletely displayed.

Presenting the screenshots of each :-

**1. Emulator Pixel 5**

[image]

**2. Device OnePlus5t**

[image]

look at the labels and text bellow the button

1. **'Username'** is displayed as **'Usernam'**. Here the last character **'e'** is missing.
2. **'Password'** is displayed as **'Passwor'**. Here the last character **'d'** is missing.
3. **'Login here'** is displayed as **'Login'**. Here the last word **'here.'** is missing.

code snippet for the Screen.

**1. RegisterScreen.tsx**

```
import { Text } from '@components';
import { useAlertToast } from '@hooks';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { setAuthState, useRegisterMutation } from '@store';
import { Button, Center, FormControl, Input, Link, Stack, WarningOutlineIcon } from 'native-base';
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Controller, useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import { KeyboardAvoidingView, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { StackNavProps } from 'StackNavigation';

import { saveEntryAsJson } from '../../utils/AsyncStorage';
import { Screens } from '../../utils/constants';

type RegisterationForm = {
  name: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
};

export const Register = () => {
  const {
    control,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm<RegisterationForm, any>({
    defaultValues: {
      name: "",
      email: "",
      password: "",
    },
  });

  const { navigate } = useNavigation<StackNavProps>();

  const [register, registerResult] = useRegisterMutation();
  const { showErrorToast } = useAlertToast();
  const dispath = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (registerResult.isSuccess) {
      saveEntryAsJson("userData", registerResult.data);
      dispath(setAuthState(registerResult.data));
      navigate(Screens.VERIFY_OTP);
    } else if (registerResult.isError) {
      //@ts-ignore
      showErrorToast(registerResult.error.data.message);
    }
  }, [registerResult.isSuccess]);

  const onSubmit = useCallback(async (data: RegisterationForm) => {
    await register({
      ...data,
    }).unwrap();
  }, []);

  return (
    <KeyboardAvoidingView style={styles.container}>
      <Center style={styles.innerContainer}>
        <FormControl isInvalid={!!errors.name} marginY={3}>
          <Stack mx="4">
            <FormControl.Label>
              <Text style={styles.inputLabel}>Username </Text>
            </FormControl.Label>
            <Controller
              control={control}
              rules={{
                required: true,
              }}
              render={({ field: { onChange, onBlur, value } }) => (
                <Input
                  onBlur={onBlur}
                  onChangeText={onChange}
                  value={value}
                  placeholder="Enter user name"
                />
              )}
              name="name"
            />
            {errors.name?.type === "required" && (
              <FormControl.ErrorMessage
                leftIcon={<WarningOutlineIcon size="xs" />}
              >
                User name is required
              </FormControl.ErrorMessage>
            )}
          </Stack>
        </FormControl>
        <FormControl isInvalid={!!errors.email} marginY={3}>
          <Stack mx="4">
            <FormControl.Label>
              <Text style={styles.inputLabel}>Email </Text>
            </FormControl.Label>
            <Controller
              control={control}
              rules={{
                required: true,
                // pattern: RegExp("/^w+([.-]?w+)*@w+([.-]?w+)*(.ww+)+$/"),
              }}
              render={({ field: { onChange, onBlur, value } }) => (
                <Input
                  onBlur={onBlur}
                  onChangeText={onChange}
                  value={value}
                  placeholder="Enter email address"
                  keyboardType="email-address"
                />
              )}
              name="email"
            />
            {errors.email?.type === "pattern" && (
              <FormControl.ErrorMessage
                leftIcon={<WarningOutlineIcon size="xs" />}
              >
                Invalid email address
              </FormControl.ErrorMessage>
            )}
            {errors.email?.type === "required" && (
              <FormControl.ErrorMessage
                leftIcon={<WarningOutlineIcon size="xs" />}
              >
                Email address required
              </FormControl.ErrorMessage>
            )}
          </Stack>
        </FormControl>
        <FormControl isInvalid={!!errors.password} marginY={3}>
          <Stack mx="4">
            <FormControl.Label>
              <Text style={styles.inputLabel}>Password</Text>
            </FormControl.Label>
            <Controller
              control={control}
              rules={{
                required: true,
                minLength: 8,
              }}
              render={({ field: { onChange, onBlur, value } }) => (
                <Input
                  onBlur={onBlur}
                  onChangeText={onChange}
                  value={value}
                  placeholder="Enter password"
                  type="password"
                />
              )}
              name="password"
            />
            {errors.password?.type === "minLength" && (
              <FormControl.ErrorMessage
                leftIcon={<WarningOutlineIcon size="xs" />}
              >
                Atleast 8 characters are required.
              </FormControl.ErrorMessage>
            )}
            {errors.password?.type === "required" && (
              <FormControl.ErrorMessage
                leftIcon={<WarningOutlineIcon size="xs" />}
              >
                Password required.
              </FormControl.ErrorMessage>
            )}
          </Stack>
        </FormControl>
        <Button
          colorScheme={"orange"}
          style={styles.registerButton}
          onPress={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
        >
          {"Register "}
        </Button>
        <Link style={styles.otherLink} onPress={() => navigate(Screens.LOGIN)}>
          <Text>Already registered?. Login here.</Text>
        </Link>
      </Center>
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  inputLabel: {
    fontWeight: "700",
    color: "black",
  },
  innerContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingHorizontal: 5,
  },
  registerButton: {
    borderRadius: 5,
    padding: 5,
    marginTop: 20,
  },
  otherLink: {
    marginTop: 10,
  },
});
```

**2. Text Component**

```
import { ITextProps, Text as NativeText } from 'native-base';

export const Text = ({ children, ...rest }: ITextProps) => {
  return (
    <NativeText
      _light={{ color: "black" }}
      _dark={{ color: "white" }}
      {...rest}
    >
      {children}
    </NativeText>
  );
};
```

I tried adding extra spaces and {" "} after the strings, but did not work. I have noticed this issue occuring on emulator sometimes while running through "Expo Go" and it gets fixed by adding an extra space after the strings, but doesn't seem to work when apk is generated.